# Find order-preserving bijection between two sets

Tags: order-theory

$$A:= (-1,0) \cup\left\{ \frac {1}{n} \,\Big\vert\, n \in \mathbb N \right\} \cup\left\{ 2- {\frac {1}{n} \,\Big\vert\, n \in \mathbb N}\right\} \cup (2,3)$$

$$B:=  (-1,0) \cup \left\{ 2- \frac {1}{n} \,\Big\vert\, n \in \mathbb N\right\} \cup (2,3)$$

with $\leq$ order of $\mathbb R$

Is $A$ isomorphic to $B$ ?

Cant find an isomorphism.

Any help please ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! Please include any of your attempts at solving the problem, or more detail about what exactly is giving you trouble.

Comment: Thanks! I got the solution for this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Those sets are not order isomorphic.

By contradiction, suppose that $\phi : A \to B$ is an order isomorphism, and consider $\phi(1)$.

Derive a contradiction for each possible case $\phi(1) \in (-1,0)$, $\phi(1) \in \{ 2- \frac {1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ and $\phi(1) \in (2,3)$ by considering $\phi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: If i take $\phi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=x \in (-1,0)$ and $\phi(1) =y \in (-1,0)$ so exist $ x<z<y $ that $\phi(\frac{1}{2}) \leq \phi(z)$ . Contradiction ? (My example for $\phi(1) \in (-1,0)$)

Comment: Correct. In that case $z \in (x,y) \subseteq (-1,0) \subseteq B$ won't have a preimage in $A$ under $\phi$.